# How to resolve hyper-V error message when booting up a VM?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, hyper-v-server-2016

I'm running this on Windows Server 2016 Essentials. There's a single local VM set up in the Hyper-V. The guest VM is Windows 10 Pro. Again, that VM runs from the same physical server.

When the host OS boots up, and I attempt to run this VM, it sometimes shows this error during the boot process of the guest/VM:

> The task you are trying to do can't be completed because Remote
>   Desktop Services is currently busy. Please try again in a few minutes.
>   Other users should still be able to log on.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8NtT.png)

Note that there are no other users or VMs present. This VM is set up on the same physical host machine. Also waiting for a few minutes doesn't help. The only resolution is not force-close the VM and restart it.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem with a Win10 laptop host and a Server 2012r2 guest. It seems to happen after the laptop wakes from hibernate.